# Why does (x-y/2)&y plot a sierpinski triangle?

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, functions

The function `(x-y/2)&y = 0` can be used to plot a sierpinski triangle. For example:

[image: sierpinski]

Why does this happen?

Comment: See [this link](http://www.maplesoft.com/applications/view.aspx?SID=5564&view=html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function computes the parity of the values in the Pascal Triangle. 
To prove that the output resembles a Sierpinski triangle (of course it's just a finite representation of this...) you may just show that the parity structure for rows $1$ to $2^k$ is repeated at the left and the right side for rows $2^k+1$ to $2^{k+1}$, and that the middle part always has even values. It's just some manipulation of $C(k,n)$ :-)